# Reactive form to create and edit information

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I am beginner in Angular, I am working with users information so, in my page I have the option to create a new user, in down I have a table that show the user's information. In this I have 3 buttons, Details, Edit and Drop, I have a modal to see and edit the information so, I am using a index to know what is the "row" or "user" selected, Details and Delete are working fine; but when I test the edit function is getting a empty form to my service, is strange because when I click again on edit for this particular user the "new" information is there. I am trying to use the same reactive Form that I am using for create new user . Someone can help me to undestand what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot

This is my html table-modal code

```
<table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Last Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Country</th>
                  <th>State</th>
                  <th>Rol</th>
                  <th>Details</th>
                  <th>Edit</th>
                  <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr
                  *ngFor="let user of userMngmtService.getListUsers() | paginate: {  itemsPerPage: 20, currentPage: 1 } let i = index"
                  [ngClass]="{restrictionColor: user.requiredFag==true}" [attr.data-index]="i">
                  <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.lastname }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.country }}</td>
                  <td>Active</td>
                  <td>
                    <option *ngFor="let role of this.userMngmtService.getListRoles()"
                      [selected]="user.aptUserRoleEntity.user_role_id === role.role_id">
                      {{user.aptUserRoleEntity.user_role_id === role.role_id ? role.name : ''}}
                    </option>
                  </td>

                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-download float-right" data-toggle="modal"
                      [attr.data-target]="'#exampleModal' + i" (click)="details(user,this.userDetails = true)">
                      <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    </button> </td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-download float-right" data-toggle="modal"
                      [attr.data-target]="'#exampleModal' + i" (click)="editUser(user,this.userEdit = true)">
                      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    </button></td>
                  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-download float-right" (click)="deleteUser(user.user_id)">
                      <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                    </button>
                  </td>
                  <!--Modal to Edit -"userEdit == true" /View Details - userDetaile == true-->
                  <div class="modal fade" id="{{'exampleModal' + i}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <label *ngIf="userDetails === true">User Details</label>
                          <label *ngIf="userEdit === true">Edit User</label>
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="router-container data-mapping-block">
                            <div class="card">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="container-fluid my-3">
                                  <div class="cards">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                      <div class="tabbable-responsive">
                                        <div class="tabbable">
                                          <form class="toppart" (ngSubmit)="editUserInformation()" #frmUser="ngForm">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                              <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col col-3">
                                                  <label> Name<small>*</small></label>
                                                  <label class="custom-control" *ngIf="this.userDetails === true"> :
                                                    {{user.name}} </label>
                                                  <input class="custom-selectbox" *ngIf="this.userEdit === true "
                                                    type="text" class="form-control"
                                                    value="{{ user.name !=='null' ? user.name :  ''}}" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col col-3">
                                                  <label> Last Name<small>*</small></label>
                                                  <label *ngIf="this.userDetails === true"> : {{user.lastname}} </label>
                                                  <input *ngIf="this.userEdit === true " type="text"
                                                    class="form-control"
                                                    value="{{ user.lastname !=='null' ? user.lastname :  ''}}" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col col-3">
                                                  <label> Email <small>*</small></label>
                                                  <label *ngIf="this.userDetails === true"> : {{user.username}} </label>
                                                  <input *ngIf="this.userEdit === true " type="text"
                                                    class="form-control"
                                                    value="{{ user.username !=='null' ? user.username :  ''}}" />
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col col-3">
                                                  <label> Country <small>*</small></label>
                                                  <label *ngIf="this.userDetails === true"> : {{user.country}} </label>
                                                  <select *ngIf="this.userEdit === true">
                                                    <option *ngFor="let country of this.listCountries"
                                                      [selected]="user.country === country.name" [value]="country.name">
                                                      {{country.name}}
                                                    </option>
                                                  </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col col-3">
                                                  <label> Role <small>*</small></label>
                                                  <div class="custom-control" *ngIf="this.userDetails === true">
                                                    <option *ngFor="let role of this.userMngmtService.getListRoles()"
                                                      [selected]="user.aptUserRoleEntity.user_role_id === role.role_id">
                                                      {{user.aptUserRoleEntity.user_role_id === role.role_id ? role.name : ''}}
                                                    </option>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <select *ngIf="this.userEdit === true">
                                                    <option *ngFor="let role of this.userMngmtService.getListRoles()"
                                                      [selected]="user.aptUserRoleEntity.user_role_id === role.role_id">
                                                      {{user.aptUserRoleEntity.user_role_id === role.role_id ? role.name : role.name}}
                                                    </option>
                                                  </select>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>

                                          </form>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-reset" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-submit" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="editUserInformation(frmUser)">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
<table>
```

Typescript: As u can see I am using a boolean variable to know if the user is editing or seing the details

```
editUserInformation(usernameEdited: any) {
    console.log('EDIT DETAILS', usernameEdited);
    let saveUserInformation = {
      name: this.userEdit == true ? this.dataUser.name : this.dataUser.name,
      lastname: this.userEdit == true ? this.dataUser.lastname : this.dataUser.lastname,
      username: this.userEdit == true ? this.dataUser.email : this.dataUser.email,
      password: this.userEdit == true ? this.dataUser.password : this.dataUser.password,
      country: this.userEdit == true ? this.dataUser.country : this.dataUser.country,
      updated_by: localStorage.getItem('usernameUserIn'),
      aptUserRoleEntity: {
        user_role_id: this.userEdit == true ? this.dataUser.role : this.dataUser.role
      }
    }
    console.log('EDIT DETAILS', saveUserInformation);
    //this.sendUserData(user);
  }
```

Comment: you need use or Template driven Forms or Reactive Forms, check the docs:https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview. NOTE: personally I prefer ReactiveForms but you can choose the two aproach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly created Form controls are no longer needed; because the ngModel creates them automatically!

```
<input 
    class="custom-selectbox" 
    *ngIf="this.userEdit === true " 
    type="text" 
    #name = 'ngModel'
    [(ngModel)] = 'user.name'
    (ngModeChange) = 'user.name = onPropertyChanged(name);       
   />

 //javascript code

await onPropertyChanged(ngModel){
   //can do async work here like  await getAllThings();
   return ngModel.viewModel;
}
```

ngModel will contain an automatically created formControl for your inspection via the onPropertyChanged routine.

Comment: John, please, don't make so categorically sentence as "Form controls are no longer needed". It's only your **personal** opinion (furthermore it's incorrect: FormControls are necessary in severals times and simplify some problems others times)

Comment: You must not understand that the ngModel contains a FormContol which is auto-created.   So there's no reason to explicitly create them.

Comment: yes, in the property "control" of an ngModel you has a "FormControl", but for me is confussed the phrase "Form controls are no longer need", for me this phrase implie that you can forget all about Reactive Forms, and I don't agree with this idea, but I want't discus about it, I'm too old for this

Comment: But you don't explain why if they are automatically created, we still need to create them explicitly.  You're not too old, you're simply refusing to see they aren't needed explicitly.  I updated the answer.

Comment: John, I suppose that if the Angular's guys create ReactiveForms and they recommend use it for large forms and see advantages in scalability or testing should be good learn about it. If I need make a complex validation, use setValidator and a ViewChild is not confortanble for me

Comment: No, they don't say that ngModel is not longer supported with Forms or Reactive Forms, they say that you can not use in **the same** tag `input` [formControl] and [(ngModel)] or [ngModel], but you can use a [(ngModel)] inside a form to manage a variable that not belong to the FormGroup or even a FormControl, a silly example: `[ngModel]="control.value" (ngModelChange)="control.setValue($event)"` and sorry if you think I'm pestering anyone, this never was my intention

Comment: Ok I stand corrected, however, using only ngModel is superior in my opinion.  There's no reason to explicitly create Form Controls.